# Ionic 2 in Genymotion: Failed to load resource (es6-shim.map and Reflect.js.map)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, genymotion, ionic2

When emulating my Ionic 2 project using Genymotion, I get these errors in the console logs:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND      file:///android_asset/www/build/js/Reflect.js.map
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND      file:///android_asset/www/build/js/es6-shim.map
```

I've been unable to navigate my app only on the emulator (the app freezes when navigating by button press) and was wondering whether these errors were causing the problem and whether there is a fix. Thanks!

Note: neither the app freezing nor these errors appear when I use ionic serve.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just forgot to do

```
ionic build android
```

Comment: This should probably be a comment.